Wifi does not work after updating drivers, how to fix it?
I have an older laptop, Acer e5-572. I have set up dual boot: Windows 10 and Ubuntu 22.04. I only use Ubuntu on the laptop.
The internal wifi card worked fine since I set up Ubuntu, for ~4 months. Now, after a recent upgrade, the wifi does not work, wifi device is not shown.
I'm not exactly sure what got updated, and how to do a rollback if possible.
If I launch Windows 10 on the same laptop, the internal wifi card is recognized and works, so I assume this is a Ubuntu driver issue.
"wlx98ded008cba7" is an external card I am using temporarily.
In the settings, it says: No wi-fi adapter found.
I found a script for generating a report on wifi issues here:
https://askubuntu.com/a/425205/40018
wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info &&
  chmod +x wireless-info &&
  ./wireless-inf

This is the output of running the script, and posting a link because the content exceeds the 30k symbol limit:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/XjR3cSh6QN/
I am also posting the output of running other commands I came across while trying to fix the issue.
How can I diagnose and fix this problem? I will provide any additional information needed, just ask.
Running nmcli --get-values GENERAL.DEVICE, GENERAL.TYPE device show shows this:
virbr0                                                                                                  
bridge                                                                                      
enp7s0f1                                                                                              
ethernet
lo                                                                                                  
loopback

This is from hardinfo tool, Network Interfaces:
-Network Interfaces-
lo  1,27MiB 1,27MiB 127.0.0.1   
enp7s0f1    0,00MiB 0,00MiB     
virbr0  0,00MiB 0,00MiB 192.168.122.1   
wlx98ded008cba7 0,18MiB 0,10MiB 192.168.8.49    

This is the output of lspci -k:
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)                                                                                                    
        Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller
        Kernel modules: ie31200_edac
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)                                                                                          
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport  
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)                                                                                       
        Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
        Kernel driver in use: i915  
        Kernel modules: i915                                                                         
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
        Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 05)      
        Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI
        Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd                                                               
        Kernel modules: xhci_pci   
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)                                                                                        
        Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller
        Kernel driver in use: mei_me
        Kernel modules: mei_me
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
        Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d5)
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev d5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 05)
        Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI
        Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM86 Express LPC Controller (rev 05)
        Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] HM86 Express LPC Controller
        Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
        Kernel modules: lpc_ich
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller
 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 05)
        Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller
 1 [AHCI mode]
        Kernel driver in use: ahci
        Kernel modules: ahci
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
        Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
        Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
        Kernel modules: i2c_i801
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 840M] (rev a2)
        Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] GM108M [GeForce 840M]
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia
        Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
07:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8411B PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] RTL8411B PCI Express Card Reader
        Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci
        Kernel modules: rtsx_pci
07:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Et
hernet Controller (rev 12)
        Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
        Kernel driver in use: r8169
        Kernel modules: r8169
08:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc BCM43142 802.11b/g/n

Output of rfkill list

0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: acer-bluetooth: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
5: phy2: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no


Could it be blocked? Please do rfkill list.

Does this answer your question? My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?

@Jos I added the output of "rfkill list".

@waltinator It has given me more information but I have not resolved the issue. I posted a link to a log file.

I noticed 1. You have IPv6 enabled, but the Wi-Fi base station seems unhappy, disable IPv6 in Settings-> Network -> interface

Does it work from a live USB of Ubuntu? That might give you more info as to whether it is a config problem with your current install

@moo I have not tested that, and won't be able to for the next few days.

You lspci -k output shows there's no loaded module handling your adapter, perhaps just missing drivers? Please refer to this and report back (I'm not 100% sure the guide is still relevant but I'd try nonetheless): https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers

lsusb run that from terminal https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting-hardware-check.html.en. is  192.168.8.49 correct ip?
